# How to get EXIF data of an image, using Nativescript?

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to read the Exif data of an image, in Nativescript. I rely on a native Java code i saw in a tutorial:

```
Uri uri; // the URI you've received from the other app
InputStream in;
try {
  in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
  ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(in);
  // Now you can extract any Exif tag you want
  // Assuming the image is a JPEG or supported raw format
} catch (IOException e) {
  // Handle any errors
} finally {
  if (in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {}
  }
}
```

This is my attempt to implement it with JS:

```
import * as application from "application";

 getExif(src){//The src is a path to a file in the camera folder
        const contentResolver = application.android.nativeApp.getContentResolver();
        const stream =  contentResolver.openInputStream(src);
        const exif = new android.support.media.ExifInterface(st)//This throws an error

    }
```

I get this error:

> Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT). ======= Check the 'adb
>   logcat' for additional information about the error

What is the problem with my code?

Update:

app.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
  compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0'
}
```

It now actually seems to me that the error is thrown before i even try to use the plugin. It actually fails here:

```
 const contentResolver = application.android.nativeApp.getContentResolver();

  const st = contentResolver.openInputStream(src);//FAIL
```

I get the error i mentioned initially.

Comment: Have you listed `com.android.support:exifinterface` as a dependency in your `app.gradle` file?

Comment: So i tried doing it, and i get "Could not find com.android.support:exifinterface:.". I checked my build.gradle file, and it seems the google() repository is already included. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you update question with your `app.gradle` content?

Comment: So i managed to get that support library going, but i still get the original error. i've updated my message

Comment: You would get the original error only if your support library is not installed. By the way what is the version of Android you are using?

Comment: Is it possible i'm supplying a bad URL for this openInputStream function? my url is just a path, like that: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190518_225049.jpg"

Comment: Can we continue this in the chat? my emulator is  android 8.1 api 27, if this is what u mean

Comment: Could be, either file not exists or if you don't have permission to read the file (external storage read).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193594/discussion-between-sheff2k1-and-manoj).

Comment: I see this readInputStream expects some Uri object. Maybe i need to create such an object, instead of passing a string? This Java confuses me :D

Comment: How you are reading the camera file path? Are you going through reading the file entries in folder path? If you use media store you will get uri of camera image right away.

Comment: I'm using the path returned from a plugin called. It works for everything else. It also requests for permissions. The path looks something like this: /storage/IDCM/camera...

Comment: @sheff2k1, I suggest you take a look at the camera plugin. The exif data is already read there: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/d68b7b6f8f11a47730304003fc8907ddee065716/src/camera.android.ts#L114

Comment: Dimitry, i'm reading the files directly from camera folder, without taking those pictures through my app. Will this plugin help with this? Anyway i managed to solve the problem with the ExifInterface: All i had to do is pass the path to the image, without dealing with any contentResolver and inputStream :D